# How to add run_list automatically when a server is created?

Tags: server, automation, continuous-integration, chef-infra, devops

In my work environment we have a hybrid cloud platform.
For Dev purpose we create and destroy many nodes specific to some applications.

So i used to configure all the these nodes when they spin up.

I have a doubt how can we automated the addition of runlist to a server 
when they are created.

My work around is to create a repo in Git and connect it to the Jenkins build which add the server to its own specific run list.

And we will be maintaining Repo specific to application.

Is there any other better way than this??

FYI, the server is getting bootstrapped when it is spinned up by a specific shell script that we maintain.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would normally set the run list as part of the bootstrap, so I would modify the shell script that does the bootstrap to pass through the appropriate arguments or files.